# Quick algorithm for finding real solutions for a system polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms, real-algebraic-geometry

Would you please recommend a computer program that could give quick answer Yes/No for the question: does there exist a real solution of a given system of polynomial equations with integer coefficients. I will need it to solve a huge list of such systems, each of them is over $\mathbb{R}^6$, has $6$ equations of degree $4$ or less. Coefficients are also quite small.
Maple's Triangularize procedure for most of the cases works too long, so applying it for big list is almost impossible.

Comment: How dense are your polynomials?

Comment: Also, what do the monomials look like (that is, do variables actually appear with degree 4, or is the degree of any given variable bounded by 1 or 2?)


Comment: Take a look at the implementation of Tarski-Seidenberg Theorem explained at http://xorshammer.com/2009/05/14/a-suite-of-cool-logic-programs I do not know whether this particular implementation is efficient, but it seems worth trying (easy to install, ...).

Comment: I asked a similar question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1493/software-for-rigorous-optimization-of-real-polynomials, have a look at the answers. QEPCAD somewhat faster than Maple/Mathematica, but less pleasant to use. If you problem allows, try solving over complex numbers, and then restrict.

Comment: If the OP's problem is "generic", then, since the number of equations equals the number of unknowns, the solution is a zero-dimensional variety, the number of complex points of which is bounded by the product of the degrees, or 4096, so the problem should not be so bad by sub-resultants.


Comment: Igor, in the beginning I am interested in those systems which are zero-dimensional. So yes, the number of solutions is not astronomically big, but computing them is not a straight-forward thing. Maples' "solve" procedure expresses solutions as algebraic expressions of "RootOf(some polynomial P_i)", but it's a problem - to check if the polynomial has real root or not, and it turns to mess if one polynomial P_j has coefficient depending on the solution of P_j.

Would you please tell me where I can find a link to "sub-resultants" method you noted?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought obtain a Groebner basis of the set of defining polynomials of your system? Maybe, it could simplify considerably the aspect of the system, and you would need a little time to calculate the real solutions of the system. For that, you could use the free software wxMaxima. If you don't have it, you can download in http://maxima.sourceforge.net/download.html.

I would like post this comment just as a comment and not as an answer, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Mathematica and Maple also can find Groebner basis quite effectively. In Mathematica there is also `FindInstance[]`, which finds an instance of solution or gives an empty list if it can't find any. I don't know if it work always. May be a combination of both could help.

Comment: I need the process to be very automatical, as there is a huge list I of systems I want to check. Dealing with each of the systems is not a hard problem, but it's a "handmade" work, I won't be able to check all the systems by hand. Most of software can compute Groebner basis, but is there a fast algorithm which can say Yes/No to real roots problem, having a Groebner basis of the ideal?