# Bounding Euler products (or almost) by products of zeta functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, products

Let $s_1, s_2 \in (1/2,1\rbrack$. I would like to bound the product

$$A=\prod_p \left(1 + \frac{p^{-s_1} p^{-s_2}}{(1-p^{-s_1}+p^{-1}) (1-p^{-s_2}+p^{-1})}\right)$$

Now, I am almost positive that  $$A\leq \frac{\zeta(s_1+s_2) \zeta(2 s_1+ s_2) \zeta(s_1+2s_2)}{\zeta(s_1+2) \zeta(s_2+2) \zeta(4)}$$ Is this (or results like this) known? Is there an elegant way to show this?

(It does seem to be the case that every term in the infinite product on the left is less than the corresponding term in the (implicit) infinite product on the right (where we expand the zeta function as its Euler product), but of course that remains to be proven.)

Comment: I have edited to improve readability. I think maybe an $s_1$ in the first display ought to be an $s_2$, but I'll leave it to OP to edit that in, if warranted. 

Comment: I've just corrected that :*) .

Comment: What I would do is just use a computer program to expand out the infinite series on each side (for each prime $p$) and subtract.  Presumably the lower-order terms vanish.  Then hopefully the first nonvanishing term is patently nonnegative and the tail can be bounded by this first nonvanishing term.

Comment: If you want to prove the inequality for each Euler factor, then setting $x_i=p^{-s_i}$, isn't it just a matter of checking whether some (complicated) polynomial $P(x_1,x_2)$ is $\geq 0$ on $[1/p,1/\sqrt{p}]^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, except that leaves an infinite number of primes (and polynomials) to check!

More on that: one can of course use a polynomial in three variables ($x=p^{-1}$, $y_1=p^{-s_1}$, $y_2 = p^{-s_2}$); less obviously, if
one wants to prove the slightly weaker bound with $\zeta(3)^2$ instead of $\zeta(s_1+2) \zeta(s_2+2)$ (note that would be good enough for my purposes) then one can eliminate one of the three variables by showing that $y_1 = y_2$ (or $y_i = x$ or $y_i=\sqrt{x}$) is worst possible.

Comment: - at the same time, that still leaves one with the problem of showing that a certain degree-ten polynomial in $x$, $y$ is non-negative on $\{x,y∈[0,1]:x<y<\sqrt{x}\}$ - and as far as I am aware, gnuplot is not considered to be a valid method of mathematical proof. Yes, all the lower-order terms vanish, and yes, this is automatically enough for very small $x$ (i.e., all $p$ larger than a constant) - note my request for "an elegant way"!

Comment: After some experimenting I was led to the approach that Matt Young also suggested. I used $y_j:=p^{-s_j}-p^{-1}\geq 0$ and looked at the double Taylor expansion in these variables of the difference of the Euler factors. Mathematica gave me the approximation $p^{-2}(y_1+y_2)-p^{-1}(y_1^3+y_2^3)+2p^{-1}y_1y_2-(y_1^3y_2+y_1y_2^3)$, where each coefficient is valid within $O(p^{-1/2})$. Unfortunately, the presence of positive and negative coefficients necessitate an even more precise approximation to draw a conclusion, but I fell out of mood here. 

Comment: Of course such lower-order terms will coincide on the left and right sides of the presumed inequality; that's how the product of zeta functions on the right side was chosen! As I also said - this settles the issue for p large enough, but for a given $p$ ($p=2$ or $p=3$ or $p=47$, say) the problem seems hairy (though not in any strong sense 'difficult'). I feel there has to be a good way out of this...


Comment: Regarding showing a degree ten-polynomial non-negative on $x<y<\sqrt{x}$. I asked a similar question a while back at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1493/software-for-rigorous-optimization-of-real-polynomials The answer was QEPCAD which is a software that can do quantifier elimination for the theory of real closed fields. The software is not polished, but is usable. It might, or might not choke on your polynomial (time and space complexity is large), but it is worth a try. 

Comment: In my last comment $O(p^{-1/2})$ meant relative error of the coefficients.

Comment: Boris, do you care to make your comment into an answer, so that we can all comment on it more easily? 

This certainly looks useful - though I wonder how to quote it in a paper. I was also hoping there might be an elegant proof by hand I am not seeing.

Just so that we are all on the same page - the crude bound
$A\leq \frac{\zeta(s_1+s_2)\zeta(2s_1+s_2)\zeta(s_1+2s_2)}{\zeta(3s_1+3s_2) \zeta(4s_1+s_2)\zeta(2s_1+4s_2)}$ is easy to show. I can also show prove a decent bound which, having about eleven terms on top and nine on the bottom, would induce typesetting nightmares (among other things). 

Comment: What I use for the "decent" bound is the inequality $1/(1-y+x) \leq 1 + (y-x) (y+1)$ (valid in the range given) and the facts that exp is convex-up and log is convex-up. (Just keeping the ball rolling...)

Comment: I'll delete my answer as I don't think it was helpful. I'm sorry for trying to answer before thinking enough about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on Boris's suggestion, let me tell of my mostly happy experience with QEPCAD.

First of all - QEPCAD seems to crash on three variables (at least for the slightly hairy expressions we are dealing with here). So we have to start by reducing our problem to a two-variable problem by means of human.

The inequality that $A\leq ζ(s1+s2)ζ(2s1+s2)ζ(s1+2s2)/ζ(s1+2)ζ(s2+2)ζ(4)$ would naturally rest on turns out to be false; no QEPCAD needed here (though QEPCAD caught this when fed a special value for one of the variables). If this strong inequality is true, it's doubtful it has a nice proof.

Now for the slightly weaker inequality (call it inequality B; it is neither the strongest nor the weakest one) that I mentioned above, namely:
$A\leq \frac{\zeta(s_1+s_2)ζ(2 s_1+s_2)ζ(s_1+2 s_2)}{ζ(3)ζ(3)ζ(4)}$;
this, as you can easily check, follows if we show that
$1 + \frac{y_1 y_2}{(1-y_1+x) (1-y_2+x)} \leq \frac{(1-x^3)^2 (1-x^4)}{(1-y_1 y_2) (1-y_1 y_2^2) (1- y_1^2 y_2)}$
for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ and $x\leq y_1, y_2 \leq \sqrt{x}$.

QEPCAD chokes on this. However, this human realized that, if we change variables to $x$, $s = y_1 + y_2$ and $r = y_1 y_2$, we get that we must show that a polynomial quadratic on $s$ with positive leading coefficient adopts only non-positive values within a range. Hence it is enough to check for $s$ extremal given $r$ - and this happens when either $y_1=y_2$ ($s$ is then minimal) or $y_i = x$ or $y_i=\sqrt{x}$ for some $i=1,2$ (so that $s$ is maximal).

QEPCAD proves the inequality very quickly in the first two cases. For $y_i = \sqrt{x}$, defining $x$ as $y_i^2$ (so that we have a polynomial) gives us a polynomial of degree too large for QEPCAD to handle. Inputting a stronger inequality of lower degree (with $(1-3 x^3)$ instead of $(1-x^3)^2 (1-x^4)$) makes QEPCAD give an affirmative answer, thus proving inequality B.

Comment: Hey! I liked the comment!

Comment: Dear Harald, I am glad that you deepened the intimate connection between machine and human.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I now have a follow-up question. How on earth do I list QEPCAD in the bibliography for the answer it provided?

Comment: [1] QEPCAD version ..., available at ... (BTW I would insert a follow-up question in the original question.)